# Knative image build and push fails with acces denied

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, istio, knative, kaniko

I'm trying to build and push a docker image with Knative. I have a maven java application and a multistaging `Dockerfile` that builds and runs the application:

```
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY pom.xml ./
COPY src/ ./src/
RUN mvn package


FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

ENV PORT 8080

COPY --from=build /usr/app/target/*.jar ./app.jar

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/usr/app/app.jar"]
```

I want to build and push the application to the gcr repository. So I have a `ServiceAccount` and a `Build`:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  password: ENCODED_PASS
  username: ENCODED_USERNAME
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    build.knative.dev/docker-0: https://gcr.io
  name: knative-build-auth
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "3001"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/knative-build-auth
type: kubernetes.io/basic-auth
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: knative-build
secrets:
  - name: knative-build-auth
---
apiVersion: build.knative.dev/v1alpha1
kind: Build
metadata:
  name: example-build
spec:
  serviceAccountName: knative-build
  source:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/pathtorepo.git
      revision: master
  steps:
    - name: build-and-push
      image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v0.1.0
      args:
        - --dockerfile=/workspace/Dockerfile
        - --destination=gcr.io/$projectid/my-build
```

I tried to use `kaniko-project` for this. However, there are some problems with using it. Version `0.1.0` works with a simple `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu

CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hiiiiiii"]
```

But does not support the multistaging `Dockerfile`s and fils with the access denied error. Any other version of the `kaniko` does not work, and fails.
In the logs for version 0.1.0 of the multistaging build I can see the following error:
    2019/07/02 14:43:13 No matching credentials found for index.docker.io, falling back on anonymous
    time="2019-07-02T14:43:15Z" level=info msg="saving dependencies []"
    time="2019-07-02T14:43:15Z" level=error msg="copy failed: no source files specified"

and the status of the build:

```
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2019-07-02T14:43:16Z"
    message: 'build step "build-step-build-and-push" exited with code 1 (image: "docker-pullable://gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor@sha256:501056bf52f3a96f151ccbeb028715330d5d5aa6647e7572ce6c6c55f91ab374");
      for logs run: kubectl -n default logs example-build-pod-7d95a9 -c build-step-build-and-push'
    status: "False"
    type: Succeeded
```

For any other versions of `kaniko` higher than 0.1.0 here is the error:

```
error pushing image: failed to push to destination gcr.io/star-wars-istio/reverse-function:latest: DENIED: Access denied.
```

Also in logs there is something like:

```
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0702 14:54:23.003241       1 metadata.go:142] while reading 'google-dockercfg' metadata: http status code: 404 while fetching url http://metadata.google.internal./computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/google-dockercfg
```

I found an issue in their repo which is closed. However it's still reproducible.
Here is the github [issue](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/issues/392)

I can confirm that my `ServiceAccount` is correct, since I'm able to build and push a simple docker image with this configuration.
I've also tried different images for build and push. For example the one that is described [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/knative-build-tutorials/blob/master/spring-boot/build.yaml).
Even though I've followed all the steps described there (creating my `ServiceAccount` following the instructions, which works with a simple Dockerfile), it still fails when I try to build and push my application. So when I apply the following Build:

```
apiVersion: build.knative.dev/v1alpha1
kind: Build
metadata:
  name: reverse-build
spec:
  serviceAccountName: knative-build
  source:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/lvivJavaClub/spring-cloud-functions.git
      revision: init-knative
    subPath: reverse-function
  steps:
    - name: build-and-push
      image: gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn
      args: ["compile", "jib:build", "-Dimage=gcr.io/star-wars-istio/reverse-function"]
```

The build fails and I'm getting the error in logs:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:0.9.3:build (default-cli) on project reverse: Build image failed, perhaps you should set a credential helper name with the configuration '<from><credHelper>' or set credentials for 'gcr.io' in your Maven settings: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
[ERROR] {"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication"}]}
```